# Ansible shell returns multiple values

Tags: ansible

I'm getting an unexpected behavior from executing a shell remotely with Ansible. When I execute the following command on the remote machine, the result is:

```
$ echo $(pgrep -f jboss)
13248
```

Now if I execute the command as Ansible shell I get as return multiple pids:

```
$ ansible jboss.servers -m shell -a 'echo $(pgrep -f jboss)' -u centos
10.3.9.155 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
13248 16362 16363
```

As I need to further elaborate the shell, I need to find a way to get the same result as if I'm on the remote machine. I've tried with:

```
'echo $(pgrep -f jboss | awk '{ print $1 }')'
```

But that doesn't work because the expression is already in single quotes. 
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `pgrep` returns the Ansible processes too. Try:

```
ansible jboss.servers -m shell -a 'ps ax | grep jboss'
```

then you know why you are getting the additional PIDs. One way to fix it is not to use `pgrep` and instead use `ps` and `grep`.

```
ansible jboss.servers -m shell -a 'ps ax | grep [j]boss | cut -d " " -f2'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had just to change the column to be f1 (otherwise the tty is returned). Now it works like a charm!